# How to solve this system of PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The 1-D Euler’s equation for constant pressure can be written in terms of the two equations
$$u_t + uu_x = 0, x\in\mathbb{R}, t> 0, u(x,0)=f(x)$$
$$\rho_t+\rho u_x+u\rho_x=0, x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0, \rho(x,0)=g(x)$$

Solving the first equation we get $u(x,t)=f(x-ut)$.

We substitute this for the second equation and get
$$\rho_t + \rho f'(x-ut) + u\rho_x=0$$

We choose a parametrization with respect to $s$ and get

$$\frac{dt}{ds}=1, \frac{dx}{ds}=f(x-ut), \frac{d\rho}{ds}=f'(x-ut)$$

Thus $s=t$, but... How do we now integrate $f(x-ut)$ or $f'(x-ut)$ with respect to $t$ to finally solve for $\rho$?

Comment: I am not convinced of your solution: $u(x,t)=f(x-ut)$. What is $u$ entering into the argument of $f$?

Comment: @Jon : I confirme the solution of the first ODE expressed on implicit form $u=f(x-tu)$. See my post below.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks, that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

This IS NOT AN ANSWER, but a comment, too long to be put in the comment section.

$$u_t+uu_x=0$$
The characteristic equations are :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
Necessarily $du=0$ and the first characteristic curve is $u=c_1$

From $dx-c_1dt=0$ the second characteristic curve is $x-tu=c_2$

The solution on implicit form is : $\Phi\left(u\:,\:x-tu\right)=0$ with any differentiable function $\Phi$. Solving the implicit equation for its first variable :
$$u=f(x-tu)$$
Any differentiable function $f$.

This confirmes the solution of the first ODE proposed by sequence. Moreover, puting it into the ODE shows that it agrees.

Second ODE :
$$\rho_t+\rho u_x+u\rho_x=0$$
$u_x=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x-tu)=(1-tu_x)f'(x-tu)$
$$\rho_t+\rho \:(1-tu_x)f'(x-tu)+u\rho_x=0$$
It seems that a term $(1-tu_x)$ is missing in the corresponding equation written by sequence. Don't you think so ?

Comment: Right, I forgot that $u$ is a function of $(x, t)$. BTW, why is $u=c_1$, if $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$? Say, $\partial u = 0 \implies u = c_1 + \gamma(t)$, where $\gamma(t)$ is a function of the second variable?

Comment: Also, despite your comment is very useful and spots my error in the substitution process, the original question still remains, and the problem looks now even more complicated. I.e., now we have $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = f'(x-tu)(1-tu_x)$. How do we integrate this?

Comment: Sure, the original question remains. That is why I entitled my post "Comment", not "Answer". I doubt that it could be integrated without more material. Is there no bounding condition and/or initial condition which could allows to got a bit further ?

Comment: No, all initial conditions are as stated in my original question.

Comment: By the way, you asked "why is $u=c_1$  if $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ ?". Of course $u(x,t)\neq c_1$ everywhere. $u=c_1$ only on the related characteristic curve. The same for $x-tu\neq c_2$ everywhere and $x-tu= c_2$ only on the related characteristic curve.

Comment: O.K. about the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ So, $f(x)$ is supposed to be a known function, but not explicitly given. I had missed that.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not an explicitly given function, that's the thing.

Comment: What I mean is that if we integrate $\partial u(x,t)$ with respect to one variable, then shouldn't we get a function of the other variable? Thus, I'd say, if $\partial u = 0$, doesn't this mean that we're integrating $\partial u(x,t)$ with respect to just one of the variables? Thus $\partial u(x,t) = 0$ should mean that $u(x,t) = \alpha(x)$ or $u(x,t) = \beta(t)$, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40975/discussion-between-jjacquelin-and-sequence).

Comment: What do you mean $\partial u=0$ ? I can understand $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ and then $u=\beta (t)$. Also I can understand $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ and then $u=\alpha (x)$. But I don't see any connection with what is done in the solving with the method of characteristics.